# How does persistent cache works in modern anti-virus softwares?

Tags: virus, anti-virus

I'm talking about Avast! and ESET's NOD32/SS here.
Avast! introduced this feature like a year ago (can't remember the exact date). ESET did it in version 7. Just recently.

Basically they both scan the drive, and decide what is clean. So next time they just skip those files, speeding up a full-computer scan.
But!

- How do they make sure the file didn't get infected meanwhile?
- What ways they use to store this data?

I'm curious about the technical bits.